# Как обработать случай, когда заданная точность не может быть достигнута?

Tags: c++, c, исключения, while, точность

К примеру есть такая конструкция :

```
do {
. . .

} while (fabs(x1 - x) >= eps);
```

eps задаю с клавиатуры. Но в результате тестирования оказалось, что не во всех случаях может быть достигнута заданная точность и программа просто не выдает результата. Как предусмотреть эту ситуацию?С помощью if-а? С помощью исключений?Если это возможно, то как это можно реализовать? Чтобы выводилось соответствующее сообщение и осуществлялся выход из программы.

Comment: Какого-то _универсального_ способа нет. Зависит от способа вычисления и конкретных диапазонов возможных значений переменных `x1`/`x`. На вскидку: 1) проверять, отличается ли текущее значение переменной `x1`/`x` от значения на предыдущем шаге цикла, и если нет, то прерывать цикл; 2) ввести счётчик кол-ва итераций цикла, и если превышено некоторое предельное значение, то прерывать цикл; 3) замерять время работы цикла, и если превышено некоторое предельное значение, то прерывать цикл.

Comment: Зависит от того, почему это происходит. Метод не сходится? это одно. Задали такое мелкое `eps`, что на машинном уровне что-то не ловится? Это другое. Неверно написали сам код — и такое ведь может быть. Показали бы конкретный пример...

Comment: @Harry я высчитываю интеграл с помощью метода левых прямоугольников. А в while сверяю эпсилон с разностью площадей прямоугольников с одним шагом и шагом в 2 раза больше.

Comment: А может, стоит сравнивать с шагом, в два раза *меньшим*? Покажите свой код, pls.

Answer (score 3):

Обычно ставится банальное ограничение на количество итераций. Написать можно по разному, я предпочитаю

```
constexpr std::size_t IterMax= 9999;
for(std::size_t i = 0; std::abs(x1 - x) >= eps; ++i){
    if(i == IterMax){
        break; // or throw
    }
    ...
}
```

Но тут возникает вопрос, что вообще означает невозможность достижения требуемой точности. Часто это ошибка в алгоритме, или данные, не удовлетворяющие условию сходимости.

Но может быть и такое, что eps фактически должна зависеть от данных, и вычислить ее заранее невозможно. Тогда можно попробовать использовать относительную ошибку, вроде `abs(x1 - x) / max(abs(x1), abs(x)) > 0.1`.

Или же можно проверять производную ошибки, тогда расчет заканчивается, когда ошибка перестала уменьшаться: `abs(abs(x1 - x) - prevEps) >= dEps` . Ну или аналогично можно проверять производную относительной ошибки.

Это все не отменяет необходимости подсчета итераций, иначе сложные модели не отладить.